# How to correct unexpected behaviour of cardview-v7:27.0.2

Tags: android, android-cardview

Strange issue since upgrading app SDK 23 to 27. This is what I expect (cards full width);

[image: Card full width]

This is what I get (some cards not full width). Scrolling causes cards to go full width again!

[image]

relevant code in msgh_detail.xml

```
            <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            layout="@layout/msgh_detail_list" />
```

relevant code in msgh_detail_list

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/detail_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is the code that sets up the view

```
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msgh_detail_list_item, parent, false);
        view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

And here is the code for the actual layout msgh_detail_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:id="@+id/DayMMdd"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="@string/day_mth_dte" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/arrivaltime"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/Hour_min" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:src="@drawable/status_1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:longClickable="false" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/detail_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ccecf9">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:textColorLink="#009933"
                android:layout_weight="0.97"
                android:text="@string/test_msg" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Seems straightforward enough and it worked fine before.

Maybe I've some setting or the hierarchy slightly wrong..?

Comment: your outer linear layout is closed ryt??

Comment: also share your activity s layout.. i hope you havent made the recyclerView width `wrap_content` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the recyclerView's width to **match_parent** instead of **wrap_content** in the activity layout..thats causing the problem...